# Accessing struct element in a vector

Tags: c++, struct, segmentation-fault

I have vector of elements,

```
vector<ImageData> data ;
```

here s the definition of ImageData

```
#ifndef IMAGEDATA_H
#define IMAGEDATA_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct ImageData {

                std::string cx;
                std::string cy;
                std::string cw;
                std::string ch;
                std::string ht;
                std::string wd;
                std::string ut;
                std::string rip;
                std::string imgFormat;
                std::string dIITest;
                vector<std::string> imageUrls;

                ImageData()
                {
                        cx="";
                        cy="";
                        cw="";
                        ch="";
                        ht="";
                        wd="";
                        ut="";
                        rip="foo";
                        imgFormat="";
                        dIITest="";
                        imageUrls.clear();
                }
};
```

on another method, when i try to access this struct elements as follows I get back segmentation fail.

```
for(int i = 0 ; (int) data.size();i++)
{
    cout<<data[i].rip;
}
```

essentially this code dumps.

Why is this happening ?

any ideas?

Comment: your for loop has no end condition, should be `i < (int) data.size();`. I'm not sure if this is your problem or just a copy/paste/clean problem.

Comment: Can we see the code segment where you allocate the objects that you put into the vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for` loop should be:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
                 //^^^
```